# Unable to create inline build task using CodeTaskFactory (build error MSB3758 and CS0012)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, wix, msbuild-task

I have a WiX project in Visual Studio 2010 that uses an inline MSBuild Task to set an environment variable in the "BeforeBuild" Target. The custom task previously built with no problems; however, I am now getting build errors, even though the project/solution has not changed at all since the last successful build. In fact, the same code builds correctly on another developers machine...

If I build the project from the command line, it also builds correctly. This leads me to believe that the VS 2010 environment may be somehow corrupted?

Since last building the project, I have installed a number of programs (VS 2015, .NET Core, etc). Would repairing VS 2010 be an option? I have VS 2010 SP1 installed.

The custom task is defined inline in the project file:

```
<!-- Define task to set environment variables for the current process -->
<UsingTask TaskName="SetEnvironmentVariableTask" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v$(MSBuildToolsVersion).dll">
  <ParameterGroup>
    <Name ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
    <Value ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Using Namespace="System" />
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs"><![CDATA[
      Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable(Name, Value, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);
    ]]></Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>
```

And is called in the before build target:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <SetEnvironmentVariableTask Name="WIX_TEMP" Value="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(IntermediateOutputPath)" />
</Target>
```

The build error is:

`Initializing task factory "CodeTaskFactory" from assembly "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll".`

`error MSB3758: An error has occurred during compilation`

`error CS0012: The type 'Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.`

**UPDATE 2017-01-19**

I tried using Emilio's suggestion below; however, it seems like the MSBuild variables are not being correctly set (I used a `<Message>` element to output them during the build process):

`MSBuildExtensionsPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild'`

`MSBuildAssemblyVersion = ''`

`MSBuildToolsPath = 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319'`

Also, if I look in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild` folder, I only see sub-folders for VS 2013 (12.0) and VS 2015 (14.0), not for VS 2010 (10.0)... Although I'm not sure if that's where VS 2010 would install MSBuild stuff?

Comment: According to your description, I create a simple consoleApp demo with the inline build task you posting by using visual studio 2010 sp1, it works well, please share a simple demo with could reproduce the issue via OneDrive..

Comment: @ColeWu-MSFT As stated in the question, I know the build task compiles normally. For some reason my VS 2010 environment seems to be corrupt. I shall try repairing VS 2010...

Comment: Do you resolve the issue after repairing vs2010? if the issue still exists, please feel free let me know. If the resolve the issue, please post a answer and mark it as answer, it will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: @ColeWu-MSFT I have not yet repaired VS 2010. In the end I upgraded the solution to VS 2013 and this solved the issue. I do not want to repair VS 2010 unnecessarily, as it may affect other software/lose updates (see [this link](http://superuser.com/questions/343621/)), so would prefer to be able to find a non-repair option fix :)

Comment: Since I can't reproduce your issue on my side, please provide a simple demo which I can reproduce the issue on my side via OneDrive.

Comment: In addition, based on your error message, please add related reference and check if it works. <Using Namespace="System" />
      <Using Namespace="Microsoft.Build.Framework" />

Answer (score 0):

It seems that installing VS2015 modifies some of the MSBuild variables you're using (e.g. **$(MSBuildToolsPath)**).

I had the same problem when using

```
<UsingTask TaskName="MyCustomTask" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll">
```

regardless of the `ToolsVersion` specified in the project file.

I ended up using

```
<UsingTask TaskName="MyCustomTask" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildAssemblyVersion)\Bin\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
```

Comment: Good suggestion! However, it didn't work for me :( See my edits to the question.

Comment: The reason you're missing the VS2010 folder is because [MSBuild has been part of Visual Studio only since version 2013](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio/). The reason your MSBuildAssemblyVersion is empty is described [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/52#issuecomment-88674094) I think. You might wanna try setting `ToolsVersion` in your project file to *12.0* and retry your build in VS2015. I'm not sure what will happen if you'll build it in VS2010 however.

Comment: Debugging these kinds of problems is easier if you open Visual Studio Options and go to `Projects and Solutions, Build and Run` and set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to **Diagnostic**. When building your project, look at the start of what's written to the Output Window. You'll see all the different MSBuild variables and their values.

Comment: Yes, I originally debugged the issue with Diagnostic output, but it did not lead to anything useful, hence the question here ;) I will update the question with the diagnostic build output anyway. As for the ToolsVersion/VS2015 change, that's pretty much what I ended up doing - I upgraded to VS2013 and it built without issue (see my reply to Cole Wu-MSFT above). I'm still trying to find a solution just in case it can help me/anyone else in the future :)